# Issues Using Deferred/When in jquery to defer a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

I'm really struggling with using Deferred or When with my jquery script. I've been through a number of articles here and elsewhere (including api.jquery.com) and I think I'm just a bit too beginner to understand exactly how to use these calls.

I'm trying to defer a function from running until a previous function in my script has completed.

I have

```
function datapoints () {
    //My long function here where I define $data
};
```

of which the outcome is an array named $data. I need that $data variable to be defined going into my next function, so I want to defer it.

I've tried to set up the deferral like this:

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();

deferred.resolve(datapoints());

deferred.done(function result (){
    // My function here where I use $data
        }
    );
```

I'd really appreciate some pointers on how to clean this up. I've tried recreating various examples but the result every time is a console error saying that $data is undefined. I know the code works because when I manually put in a setTimeout of a few seconds before running the second function everything works fine but I think deferred is a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so `$data` is global - like `window.$data` ? and `datapoints` and `result` use it? because you talk about `$data` and neither definition nor usage are explained

Comment: (a) show me some asynchronism, (b) what does `datapoints()` return?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - I think that's my problem, it's not actually asynchronous. datapoints() returns, as stated in the question, an [array] named data.

Comment: Meaghan, in that case you don't need a Deferred/Promise. Ignore all the attempted answers and use standard blocked code; remember that old fashioned way to program where each line executes after the previous line? :), eg. `var datapoints = makeDatapoints(); var result = makeResult(datapoints);` or `var result makeResult(makeDatapoints());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fixing your code like this:

```
deferred.done(function result (data){
    // Do not use global $data, use local 'data' instead
    }
);
```

This will ensure the data you are using is in fact the data returned by `datapoints()`.

You should also be aware, that unless `datapoints()` is an async function, the code you wrote WILL block the JS thread (i.e. if run in browser - it will block the UI).

Promises/deferreds with synchronous functions is not of much use.

The usual pattern would be something like this:

```
function datapoints() {
   var d = $.Deferred()
   asyncCallToCreateDatapoints(function callback(data) {
      d.resolve(data)
   })
   return d;
}

datapoints().done(function result(data) {
   /* do stuff with data */
})
```

Comment: I think you've inadvertently answered my question with the line "unless datapoints() is an async function, the code you wrote WILL block the JS thread (i.e. if run in browser - it will block the UI)." I don't think it's an async function. Might need to do a bit more digging.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function datapoints () {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    /* later, when data is ready, call:

        deffered.resolve(data);
    */

    return deferred.promise();
}


datapoints().then(function () {
    // runs when data is ready         
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entierly sure what your problem is, but this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84EC6/) is working fine for me.

```
function datapoints () {
    //My long function here where I define $data
    return {"datapoint1": 1, "datapoint2": 2};
};

var deferred = $.Deferred();

deferred.resolve(datapoints());

deferred.done(function result (data){
    // My function here where I use $data
    console.log("data: ", data);
});
```